# Insert Into, Conflit with Foreign Key

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-insert

```
create table Interventions
(

    InterventionID BIGINT IDENTITY (1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
    InterventionCustomerID BIGINT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Customer(CustomerID) NOT NULL,
    InterventionMalfunctionDescription NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    CustomerID BIGINT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Customer(CustomerID),
    EmployeeID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Employees(EmployeeID),
    TypeOfEquipementID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TypeOfEquipements(TypeOfEquipementID),
    StatusID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TypeOfStatus(StatusID),
    SerialNumber VARCHAR(255) FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES SerialNumbers(SerialNumber),
    GroupID INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES TypeOfGroup(GroupID) NOT NULL,
    InterventionCreateDate DATETIME NOT NULL,
    InterventionStartDate DATETIME,
    InterventionFinnishDate DATETIME,
    InterventionArchiveDate DATETIME

);

create table Customer
(
CustomerID BIGINT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
OrganizationName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
Telephone VARCHAR(255),
MobileTelephone VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
CustomerAdressLine1 VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
CustomerAdressLine2 VARCHAR(255),
PostalCode VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
FederalTaxID VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
EmailAddress VARCHAR(255) UNIQUE NOT NULL,
SageCustomerID BIGINT UNIQUE

);


INSERT INTO Interventions(InterventionCustomerID, InterventionMalfunctionDescription, CustomerID, EmployeeID, TypeOfEquipementID, StatusID, SerialNumber, GroupID, InterventionCreateDate, InterventionStartDate, InterventionFinnishDate, InterventionArchiveDate) VALUES
('1', 'abc', '4', '4', '1', '1', 'SerialNumber1', '1', '2019-01-01', '2019-01-02', '2019-01-03', '2019-01-04'),
('2', 'abc', '5', '5', '2', '2', 'SerialNumber2', '2', '2019-02-01', '2019-02-02', '2019-02-03', '2019-02-03'),
('3', 'abc', '6', '6', '3', '3', 'SerialNumber3', '3', '2019-03-01', '2019-03-02', '2019-03-03', '2019-03-04');

Select * from Customer;
```

[image]

Erro:

> The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK__Intervent__Inter__6C190EBB". The conflict occurred in database "ADSGLOBAL", table "dbo.Customer", column 'CustomerID'.

Comment: Are `CustomerID` 4, 5 and 6 present in `dbo.Customer`?

Comment: The CusomeID 4,5 and 6 they are present in dbo.Custommer

Comment: Why are you treating ***all*** of your values as ***strings***?  What happens if you try to insert one row at a time?  Do they all error, or just one or two?  Finally, what do you get from `SELECT * FROM dbo.Customer WHERE CustomerID IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6)`?

Comment: I put image about SELECT * FROM Customer;

Comment: I already fix my error thanks, guys!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a constraint on `InterventionCustomerID` that says it references `Customer(CustomerID)`.

Your insert statement says you're trying to insert the values `1`, `2`, `3` in to that column.

Your `SELECT * FROM customer` shows that customers `1`, `2`, `3` don't exist in that table.

You can't insert records for customers `1`, `2`, `3` until you've created them in the `Customer` table.

Comment: @BrunoMiguel - Then please feel free to accept this as the correct answer.  *(Click on the "Tick" mark.)*